# SoundCloud Widget - eliminate a short delay before start

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundcloud

I use SoundCloud's widget for a site's player, controlled dynamically with my code.

So when the player is ready (`player.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY...`) and the user clicks on play button, it usually delays for a very short period (500ms to 1sec, kind of) before actually playing the music.

How should I kill this short waiting gap? What I want to achieve is to make it play immediately after it's ready and the user clicks on the play button.

Comment: Hey, the media needs to be loaded in the browser, so that's the wait period, which then depends on the network quality.

Comment: I thought when it's ready it's already been loaded to the browser? So is there anyway I could make sure it's completely ready to be played?

Comment: There's the JavaScript application that is initialised. By design, the sound won't load until user at least hovers the play button – the intention is to save the bandwidth for the users that might not play the widget at all. Imagine a page with 30 widgets. Loading 30 tracks might result in a lot of waste for the user.